# help with basic MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am creating a demo MVC project and i am getting a Null Object Reference error for the following code.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
   <tr>
       <td>
           <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
           <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%> |
           <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
       </td>
       <td>
           <%= Html.Encode(item.ContactEmail) %>
       </td>
       <td>
           <%= Html.Encode(item.YourQuery) %>
       </td>
   </tr>
<% } %>
```

i get an error in the first line itself (var item in Model) coz i am getting the Model object as null.

Can anyone please help me.

thanks.

Comment: Do you use View(yourModelObject) as return in action method?

Comment: you should check first that your Model Object is null or not & if no then only foreach should get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a model in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new YourModel());
}
```

Comment: hey buddy, 
appreciate your help but i am not getting my model name when i type "(new ...)". i have added a "SQL To Linq" class as my model named "ContactUs".
Also i was trying out this code while watching a video online and they have not passed any model name in their code, but their project is running fine.

hope you got it...
thanks

Comment: hey buddy, i understood where the problem was.
and thanks for the solution.